# Why did the hole in Kaiba's chest increase in size?

Tags: kaiba

Starting out, we see that there is a pretty significantly sized hole in Kaiba's chest. Later on we see in a flashback that the hole was much smaller when he first showed at the Issoudan base.

[image: Picture comparing the two hole sizes]

The collector of Warp's clones mentioned that the hole is one of the indicators of a *true* clone, and we see that the clone in the final battle also has one. Why would the hole in Kaiba's chest have changed sizes over time?

Answer (score -1):

I can't say for sure, but IMO, the hole size probably varies depending on a Kaiba/Warp's mental state — the worse he feels, the wider it gets.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. The answer would be better if you could provide some examples/scenes/references to back up your theory by [edit]ing it :)